# Display a Simpleitk image in a picture Box

Tags: c#, system.drawing, itk, simpleitk

I want to read a dicom or png image with simpleitk in a C# program and display the result in a pictureBox. I understand that picture Box allow only "system.drawing.image" and not itk. Is there a way to do it.
 Her is my code :

```
OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
fd.Filter = "PNG|*.png";
if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string file = fd.FileName;
    ImageFileReader reader = new ImageFileReader();
    reader.SetFileName(file);
    itk.simple.Image image = reader.Execute();
     Box.Image = image;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [load a bitmap image into windows form using open file dialog!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122984/load-a-bitmap-image-into-windows-form-using-open-file-dialog)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need access to the raw image buffer which SimpleITK holds. This is accessible via the Image::GetBufferAs"TYPE" methods.

Here is a brief [example](http://www.itk.org/SimpleITKDoxygen/html/ImageGetBuffer_8cs-example.html) on using this method:

```
  // Cast so we know the the pixel type
  input = SimpleITK.Cast(input, PixelId.sitkFloat32);
  // calculate the nubmer of pixels
  VectorUInt32 size = input.GetSize();
  int len = 1;
  for (int dim = 0; dim < input.GetDimension(); dim++) {
    len *= (int)size[dim];
  }
  IntPtr buffer = input.GetBufferAsFloat();
```

I believe this can then be converted into to a [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14.aspx) with .Net.

Comment: How did you import the `Simpleitk` library? When I try to import the DLLs using `regsvr32`, getting an error like this: `SimpleITKCSharpNative.dll was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found`

Answer (score -2):

```
using (OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    fd.Filter = "PNG|*.png";

    if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Box.Image = new Bitmap(fd.FileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that i can do that but i want to use simpleitk because it's allow me to read dicom file