# Adding images within Windows form application C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am creating a pretty detailed windows form application and i know how to add pictures through the picturebox no problem, however what i am trying to do is on the running application to be able to have the user upload any images they want. Is this even possible through this IDE.

Comment: Yes? But what do you want to do with the image actually? Merely displaying it is just setting the path, but if you need saving for future use, you'd need to be more specific (saving to app folder, DB, etc)

Comment: what's your problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void buttonBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        dlg.Title = "Open Image";
        dlg.Filter = "bmp files (*.bmp)|*.bmp"; // custom filter

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            PictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Please take a look at this question: [Load a bitmap image into Windows Forms using open file dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122984/load-a-bitmap-image-into-windows-forms-using-open-file-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the `OpenFileDialog` Box filtered extensions for some image file formats like :

- .jpg,
- .gif,
- .png,
- .webp

and they will be able to upload photos from any location.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use an `OpenFileDialog`.

Using that, the User can navigate through his local files. 
So now he can select the wanted picture and *open* it. The `OpenFileDialog` will return a `String` with the location of the file.

Now you can change the `Background`, the `Button` or whatever you want to change, by using the path to the file.
You should filter the allowed files which the user is able to open via the `OpenFileDialog`, so he doesn't wind up opening the path to an `.exe` or something else.

Maybe there is an better option, but I do not know it now.

Provide a code example if you have further questions.